# Why my android studio does not look like it should?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded android studio 0.2.2 and it looks like this:
[image]

are there any themes or something? I hoped it would looke like on the google page:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the dracula theme, you can get it by going to preferences > appearance. and change "theme"